# changing UILabel text randomly in ios

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uilabel

in my app i want to change the uilabel text randomly but am not able to change randomly with the following code.

```
if (app.l == 0 || app.l%5 == 0) {
    textLabel.text = @"Just pick up a pen  and put it down on the paper.See what you create.";
}
else if(app.l == 1 || app.l%5==1)
{
    textLabel.text = @"Turn on your favourite sport event and let yourself get into it.";
}
```

Please help.
I need to change the text randomly when each time user enter in to the viewcontroller.
And is it possible to use tag to change the text.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get a random value, to do this use `arc4random()`. This returns a random number between 0 and (2**32)-1.  How does this help us?  What we really want is just two random numbers, either 0 or 1 so we can pick between our two labels. We do this by using `%`, which divides the number and gives us the remainder. If we do `arc4random()%2` we will get a 0 if the number is even, and 1 if it's odd.

If we did `arc4random()%4` we would get either 0,1,2 or 3.

EDIT: Actually the other answer is a good suggestion.  `arc4random_uniform()` will do this for us. But instead of doing `arc4random_uniform(100)/50` you can really just do `arc4random_uniform(2)`, which will return a random number of either 0 or 1.

Either way, we can use that random number in an if block to pick the text randomly. Half the time it will be zero, half the time it will not be, so use that in your else statement.

```
int randomNum = arc4random() % 2;
if (randomNum==0) {
    textLabel.text = @"Just pick up a pen  and put it down on the paper.See what you create.";
}
else
{
    textLabel.text = @"Turn on your favourite sport event and let yourself get into it.";
}
```

Comment: did this change the text reandomly when user go back and come to the particular view controller ?

Comment: what happens if we set arc4random() % 4?

Comment: It will randomly pick update the text every time it is ran.  It depends on where you put it.  Explained arc4random a bit more in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
textLabel.text = (arc4random_uniform(100)>50)?
         (@"Just pick up a pen  and put it down on the paper.See 
         what you create."):(@"Turn on your favourite sport event 
         and let yourself get into it.");
```

`arc4random_uniform(N)` returns a `NSUInteger` from 0 to `N`

if you want to add more text:

```
NSArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4",@"5", nil];
    textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(list.count)];
```

Comment: quantas 94 heavy :it's working fine.can you please explain me uniform(100)>50)

Comment: is it possible to add more than 5 text ?

Comment: @Mac_Play ofc u can. Just create NSArray with your texts. And randomly get object from this array.